# Magento Magmi remove all categories before update database with cron

Tags: magento, cron, categories, magmi

Can somebody help with Magento / Magmi for remove all categories with cron command please? I know a command for clear the catalog by this command:

php /magmi/cli/magmi.cli.php -engine=magmi_utilityengine:Magmi_UtilityEngine -pluginclass=ClearProductUtility

But how is the command for remove all categories?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you first have the Custom SQL Utility installed.

Then, try this command:

```
php /magmi/cli/magmi.cli.php -engine=magmi_utilityengine:Magmi_UtilityEngine -pluginclass=CustomSQLUtility -UTCSQL:queryfile=/absolute/path/to/magmi/plugins/utilities/customsql/prequests/removecats.sql
```

Be sure to change `/absolute/path/to/magmi/plugins/utilities/customsql/prequests/removecats.sql` to the correct absolute path of the file.